# Using find in systemd service results in error: 'paths must precede expression'

Tags: systemd, services, find

I'm trying to create an exclude file, before my backup runs. Using this simple `find` command produces the correct output, but it fails when used in a `systemd` service. I think because of `find` escaping.

Is there an alternative to chevron or piping? or a correct way to escape characters? Thanks

error: `find[20029]: /usr/bin/find: paths must precede expression:`>'

My service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Restic backup service
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/find /home/jake/finished/ -size +1G > /etc/restic/exclude_large.lst
ExecStart=/usr/bin/restic backup --verbose --one-file-system --tag systemd.timer $BACKUP_EXCLUDES $BACKUP_PATHS
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/restic forget --verbose --tag systemd.timer --group-by "paths,tags" --keep-daily $RETENTION_DAYS --keep-weekly $RETENTION_WEEKS --keep-monthly $RETENTION_MONTHS --keep-yearly $RETENTION_YEARS
EnvironmentFile=/etc/restic/restic-backup.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I solved this with the following method:

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/find /home/jake/finished/ -size +1G > /etc/restic/exclude_large.lst'
```

Comment: The point is not the backslash but that you wrote `bash -c ...` around it. That's because systemd does not understand shell redirection `>` and passes that `>` to `find` as a parameter. Encapsulating this in `bash -c` makes it a shell command and now the redirection is understood.

Comment: I naturally tried bash and sh first, without the backslash, with the same result but I have tested again just now and it works. I think I may have neglected to do a systemctl -daemon-reload...